# Why is MessageListener consuming ActiveMQ messages before a pool is ready to work on the message?

Tags: java, wildfly, activemq-artemis, java-ee-8, message-listener

Application deployed on WildFly using Java EE `javax.jms.MessageListener` to consume messages from queue.

```java
@ResourceAdapter("remote-artemis")
@MessageDriven(name = "DeliveryMDB", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "delivery_inbound"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")
})
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@Pool(value="delivery-mdb-pool")
```

This `MessageListener` consumes all messages on the queue regardless of if a *pool* is ready to work on the message. This has multiple negative effects, such as having to wait for the application to handle all messages before shutdown is triggered (problematic because we have thousands of messages in queue). If a forced shutdown is needed then all the messages are gone. We can no longer track the number of message in queue in ActiveMQ because they are all consumed.

I expected the `MessageListener` to only consume a message when a *pool* was ready. I have tried to read the ActiveMQ documentation, but cannot find anything relevant.

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: What pool are you referring to? How do you know the pool is not ready to work on the message(s)?

Comment: I have defined max 8 pools in Wildfly <strict-max-pool name="delivery-mdb-pool" max-pool-size="8" .../> I know it is not ready because I can see that I have for example put 10,000 messages on the queue, the MessageListener have only handled f.eks 1000, and the queue is empty in activeMQ. If I stop sending to the queue, the MessageListener will still handle the last 9000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell what you're seeing is the expected behavior. This is because the creation of sessions and receiving of messages by the JCA RA is independent of the instance pool size used by the EE container for the MDB.

In short, the JCA RA receives the message from the broker and passes it to an instance of the MDB. If no MDB instance is available the JCA RA just waits for one to become available. If you don't want to get into this kind of situation then you should set the `maxSession` activation configuration property on the MDB to the same value you use for the MDB instance pool (i.e. `8` in this case).

Also, aside from this, it is important to keep in mind that the core client used within the JCA RA will fetch a batch of messages all at once and buffer them so that it doesn't have to make a network round-trip to the broker for *every single message*. This is a performance optimization controlled by the `consumerWindowSize` activation configuration property and it impacts all core clients, not just ones in an EE context. This will also impact your use-case. If, for some reason, you want the message count in the broker to exactly reflect how many messages have been *consumed* and not include any buffered messages then you can set the `consumerWindowSize` to `0`, but that will negatively impact performance, potentially severely.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "8") on my MessageListener and see if that helps.